# Xcode Framework Header

Tags: xcode

When trying to make a Cocoa framework I ran into the old problem of the headers not copying, which I fixed by changing the visibility(?) of the headers to public. now I Would Like to organise the framework more logically. when the headers are copied there are are placed all in the same directory with no subfolders. I would like it to organise the framework by placing the headers in sub folders so that I can *#import* them like:

```
#import <Myframework/Math/MathFunction.h> // import some math related functions
```

however I notice that the system frameworks contain subframeworks. If I must I am willing to do that and also is there a fast way to convert all the

```
#import "someFile.h"
```

to

```
#import <Myframework/somefile.h>
```

in the release so the in other project I can *#import* them without confufing the compiler?